# Why did Zemo lead room service to discover what's in his room?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In Siberia, Zemo made a call to his German hotel to invite room service to his abandoned room and thus discover:

> the body of psychiatrist Theo Broussard.

It immediately hit the news and made Iron Man realize Captain America was right all along.

So didn't it jeopardize Zemo's entire plan? Sure, he had a better card down his sleeve, buy why not two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zemo's plan hinged on Iron Man and Captain America both following him to Siberia. He needed them both there, Iron Man to see the truth about the death of his beloved parents and Captain America there to save Bucky by fighting Iron Man.

That was his end game the whole time. Without Tony getting that hope spot that his friend could be brought back onto the same team, he wouldn't have been in that situation to fight almost to the death with him.